# Magento is automatically redirecting to localhost on live server

Tags: magento, redirect, localhost

I have uploaded my website on live server from localhost in magento

and when i m writing the url e.g: http://unbeatablewatches.com it is redirecting to localhost/unbeatable-watches..

how to solve this issue .. ?

please help me

Comment: Lol `Fatal error: Call to undefined function zn_logo() in /home/unbeatab/public_html/wp-content/themes/kallyas/header.php on line 69`

Answer (score 13):

This occurs when the base link urls are not changed in the table `core_config_data` (records with the following `path` column).

```
web/secure/base_url
web/secure/base_link_url
web/unsecure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_link_url
```

You must clear the cache after changing them.
This also occurs if the `var/cache` folder is not writable and the cache is written in the OS default `tmp` folder.

Answer (score 12):

You can use command

```
$ bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url=your.magento.url
$ bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure=your.magento.url
```

to set site urls.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change urls in database.

Table core_config_data

You need to look for this values in path column:

```
web/secure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_url
```

And change their values to https://unbeatablewatches.com for secure and http://unbeatablewatches.com for unsecure.

I don't know if you have some access to the database, it would be good if you could use phpmyadmin.

Comment: If values are there than it should be working. Check your .htaccess file maybe ? And delete your cache (delete everything inside var folder in magento folder)

Answer (score 3):

The answer that vasily-l posted is some what correct and worked for me.

However, protocols are required as per the magento documentation otherwise you will receive errors stating that the url is invalid. A trailing slash should also be used:

`$ bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.example.com/"`
`$ bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://www.example.com/"`

The commands should be run from the magento root directory.

It is also best to note that these commands would be for Magento 2.x not Magento 1.x

Source: [Magento DevDocs: Configure the store](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-store.html#instgde-cli-storeconfig)

*PS: Didn't have enough rep to comment.*

Answer (score 1):

Once I faced similar problem and the trick was I forgot to update local.xml files. I know it's old thread but if anyone runs into that.

Comment: That was it for me... crazy! I was linking to an old database. Infinite thanks for the clue...

Answer (score 0):

It was the same problem, fixed by changing in the database `WHERE path='web/secure/base_url' AND path='web/unsecure/base_url'` set `scope_id=0` and `scope=default`

besides defining the url

```
SELECT * FROM magcore_config_data WHERE path='web/secure/base_url'
SELECT * FROM magcore_config_data WHERE path='web/unsecure/base_url'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and solved it using following steps.

**1. Change base_url**

Navigate to the `core_config_data` table in your database and add
    your store url to the value column of following `path` column.

```
web/secure/base_url
web/secure/base_link_url
web/unsecure/base_url
web/unsecure/base_link_url
```

**2. Clear log entries**

Run following SQL query in order to truncate log tables.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
```