# Virtual host for magento2 under lampp service for Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, magento2, virtualhost, lampp

I tried to set virtual host for Magento2(2.2.5) Project in Ubuntu system under Lampp service.

I added this piece of code under **opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
  <VirtualHost *.:80>
  ServerName magento2.local
  DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento2/"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento2/">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

And added that under **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1     magento2.local
```

Uncommented below piece of line under **nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**

```
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Restarted the service

```
/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

After this when I try to hit **magento2.local** it again redirects with the normal URL **localhost/Magento2**

Nothing works.

Welcome for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what directory points `ServerRoot` in httpd.conf to?

Comment: Hi @Andra  this is pointed in my httpd.conf
ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"

Comment: maybe helps [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95988/magento-2-website-redirecting-to-localhost](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95988/magento-2-website-redirecting-to-localhost) or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639544/magento-is-automatically-redirecting-to-localhost-on-live-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639544/magento-is-automatically-redirecting-to-localhost-on-live-server)